# How to append semi-colon on to each element in an ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, list, selenium, arraylist, selenium-webdriver

I am currently trying to append a semi-colon onto the end of each element in an ArrayList .

The code:

```
ArrayList<String> emailAddresses = new ArrayList<String>();

public void getEmailAddresses() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.findElement(By.className("userlink-0")).click();
    String emailAddress = driver.findElement(By.id("email")).getText();
    emailAddresses.add(emailAddress);
    hs.addAll(emailAddresses);
    emailAddresses.clear();
    emailAddresses.addAll(hs);

}
```

Eventually I will be taking this list of email addresses and outputting it to the recipients field for sending an email using Java. Hence why I am trying to append semi-colons to the elements in order to separate the email addresses.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "Is it good practice to remove the comma in the list"? Which commas are you talking about?

Comment: This is a great [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info/) ! **Don't** put semi-colons in elements but rather add them when generating the "final" string. See Nicolas Filotto's answer which perfectly identified the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you use **Java 8**, you could do that using the `Stream API` with [`joining(CharSequence delimiter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) as collector *allowing to concatenate the input elements, separated by the specified delimiter, in encounter order* as next:

```
String emails = emailAddresses.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(";"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As a primitive solution you may use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < emailAddresses.size(); i++) {
    emailAddresses.set(i, emailAddresses.get(i).concat(";"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing commas with semi-colons doesn't sounds to me a full proof solution that will grantee to not break in future. Since that requires doing syso on list and then use regex to replace commas and brackets. Instead I'll use StringBuilder, iterate over the list and append semi-colons.

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i< emailAddresses.size(); i++ )
{
    str.append(emailAddresses.get(i));
    //to skip last emailAddress 
    if(i+1 == emailAddresses.size())
        continue;
    str.append(";");
}
System.out.println(str.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add semicolon to each element while adding them to ArrayList. But suppose you want to do some processing later on, so now you have to take care of that extra semicoln you have added.

So a better solution could be, just add all element as they are and just print below line on the recipient filed where you want them:

```
System.out.println(emailAddresses .toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", ";"));
```

If any problem ask in comment section.